# Connection between the cumulative distribution function and $p$-integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, lp-spaces

Let $p \geq 1$ and $l > 0$. Suppose that $X$ is a non-negative random variable with a CDF satisfying for some constant $c > 0$, $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(x^l(1 - F_X(x))) = c$.

I have to show that a non-negative random variable $X$ is $p$-integrable iff $p < l$. I already know that the expected value of a non-negative r.v. can be expressed as $E(X) = \int_0^\infty(1 - F_X(x))dx$, and for $X^p$, $E(X^p) = \int_0^\infty px^{p-1}(1 - F_X(x))dx$.

I'm not looking for a complete answer, but some hints would be nice as currently I don't have any clue on how to start the proof. To be specific, I don't know how to use the fact that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(x^l(1 - F_X(x))) = c$ with the CDF form of the moment $p$ of $X$.

Comment: Hint: the fact that $\lim x^\ell (1-F(x))=c$ implies that for large enough $x$, $x^\ell (1-F(x))<c+\epsilon$. This gives you an upper bound on $1-F(x)$ that you can apply to the equation $E[X^p]=\int_0^\infty px^{p-1}(1-F(x))\,dx$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I feel like you're going to have to give me more rope. Now what I've done is I've done is that I've chosen $\epsilon > 0$, $\delta_\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $1 - F(x) < \frac{c + \epsilon}{x^l} \leq \frac{c + \epsilon}{\delta_{\epsilon}^l}$ for all $|x| \geq \delta$. But this only yields $E[X^p] < \int_0^\infty px^{p-1} \frac{c + \epsilon}{x^l}dx =p(c + \epsilon)\int_0^\infty  \frac{x^{p-1}}{x^l}dx$ where the upper bound either diverges or is not defined.

Comment: You are close (one could say you are only epsilon away!). Note that the bound $1-F(x)< (c+\epsilon)/x^\ell$ only applies when $x> \delta$. Therefore, when upped bounding the integral $\int_0^\infty px^{p-1}(1-F(x))\,dx$, you need to split the integral into $\int_0^\delta$ and $\int_\delta^\infty$. The first integral can be proved finite without using the bound on $1-F(x)$ you derived. For the second integral, you do use the bound, and since we eliminated zero from the integration region, the upper bound will be finite.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I think I got it in the first direction: Since the integral $\int_0^\delta$ is nothing but $E(X^p*1_{[0, \delta)})$, we may use the $p$-integrability of $X$ and the monotonicity of the integral to conclude that it is finite. Then, the second integral $\int_\delta^\infty$ yields that $p < l$. I was also wondering how to attack the "only if" direction: Choosing the $\epsilon, \delta$ as before and splitting the integral into the two parts yields that $\int_\delta^\infty$ is finite after using $p < l$. However, how could you show that $\int_0^\delta$ is finite as well (continues)?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Namely, while we could estimate the $px^{p-1}(1 - F(x))$ upwards with $\frac{c + \epsilon}{x^\alpha}$, we'd run into the problem of the lower bound $0$ with exponents $p$ and $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $\epsilon>0$, so that $\epsilon < c$. There exists $\delta$ so that
$$
x>\delta \quad \implies \quad c-\epsilon < x^\ell (1-F(x))< c+\epsilon \tag1
$$
Now, write
$$
E[X^p]=\underbrace{\int_0^\delta px^{p-1}(1-F(x))\,dx}_{\text {finite}}+\int_\delta^\infty px^{p-1} (1-F(x))\,dx
$$
The first integral is always finite, so we focus on the second. Using $(1)$, you can show the second integral is finite when $p<\ell$ and infinite when $p\ge \ell$.

Further details:

> When $p<\ell$, you show the second integral is finite by using$$\int_\delta^\infty px^{p-1} (1-F(x))\,dx<\int_\delta^\infty px^{p-1} x^{-\ell} (c+\epsilon)\,dx$$
>
>   When $p\ge \ell$, you can show the second integral is infinite by using$$\int_\delta^\infty px^{p-1} (1-F(x))\,dx>\int_\delta^\infty px^{p-1} x^{-\ell} (c-\epsilon)\,dx$$